# OpenPYXL Python errors on cell values

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an excel file with a ton of rows, and a column containing HZ, NZ or SZ now is this erroring out, and I have no idea on how to fix it.

```
region    = ws.cell(row=srow, column=3)

if region.value == "HZ":
    nregion = "Houston"
elif region.value == "NZ":
    nregion = "North"
elif region.value == "SZ":
    nregion = "South"
```

It errors with the following messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PowerExp.py", line 18, in <module>
    wb=load_workbook(filename = wbfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 136, in load_workbook
    _load_workbook(wb, archive, filename, use_iterators, keep_vba)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 171, in _load_workbook
    style_table = read_style_table(archive.read(ARC_STYLE))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/reader/style.py", line 42, in read_style_table
    font_list = parse_fonts(root, xmlns, color_index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/reader/style.py", line 160, in parse_fonts
    font.size = font_node.find(QName(xmlns, 'sz').text).get('val')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I can't change the value and save the workbook as it is automatically retrieved from the email server and loaded into MySQL.

Comment: Looks like you're using a very old version of the library. Try updating it.

Comment: I have the same issue as of openpyxl 2.5.1